# Fetch new entries in a RSS with node.js

Tags: node.js, rss

I am trying to write a nodejs script that runs daily as a scheduled task. The goal of the script is to fetch **new** entries on a RSS Feed and process certain actions on those new entries.

I am not sure how to track what entries are new and which ones were processed on previous days.

Is there any package that I could use for this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any package that would allow you to do the diffing (keeping track of old vs. new entries). In practice, you'll have to keep track of the entries you've already seen yourself, using the `<id>` or `<guid>` elements, or the `<link>` elements if you don't want dupes in links.

You could also use a solution like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com), which I created and does exactly that on your behalf. Give us feed urls and we'll push you in real time the new entries.

Comment: What do you mean with "you will push me"?

Comment: Well, exactly that. We push you the data either thru XMPP or a webhook (PubSubHubbub). You won't need to poll the feeds at all.